# Flink TaskManager cannot connect to JobManager in docker swarm task

Tags: apache-flink, docker-swarm, akka-cluster, docker-swarm-mode

I cannot manage to make a TaskManager communicate with the JobManager on a docker swarm stack.

The content of the `stack.yml` file I use to `docker stack deploy` is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: affo/flink:1.1.3
    ports:
      - "48081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    networks:
      - my-net
    deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 1
        restart_policy:
            condition: none
        placement:
            constraints:
                - node.role == manager

  taskmanager:
    image: affo/flink:1.1.3
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    networks:
      - my-net
    deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 4
        restart_policy:
            condition: none
        placement:
            constraints:
                - node.role != manager

networks:
    my-net:
        external: true
```

Docker image `affo/flink:1.1.3` is a push on dockerhub of the image built following the README @ https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.1.3-rc2/flink-contrib/docker-flink.

Network `my-net` is an overlay attachable network.

I tried to ping every container from others using DNS resolution and everything works correctly.

However no TaskManager can make it through to the JobManager.

I report the JobManager log: http://pastebin.com/Ai5s4Xvr

And the log of one TaskManager: http://pastebin.com/ty5pZhSp

The JM has VIP 10.0.42.7. And `jobmanager.rpc.address` is set to `jobmanager` which resolves to 10.0.42.7.

Any help or hint on where to start solving the problem would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

I add the output of `docker exec <jobmanager> netstat -tulpn`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:40762        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.42.7:6123   :::*                    LISTEN      218/java
tcp        0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      218/java
tcp        0      0 :::34963                :::*                    LISTEN      218/java
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:57000        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

And of `docker exec <a_taskmanager> telnet jobmanager 6123`:

```
telnet: can't connect to remote host (10.0.42.7): Connection refused
```

I also put a link to a maybe-related issue on github: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28795.

Thanks again

**UPDATE**

I recently managed to change the `jobmanager.rpc.address` to `0.0.0.0` only at the JobManager's and now it is effectively listening:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:56218        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::6123                 :::*                    LISTEN      218/java
tcp        0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      218/java
tcp        0      0 :::55231                :::*                    LISTEN      218/java
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:47549        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

I can even `nc` or `telnet` from TaskManagers.

However, now the problem is (on the JobManager):

```
2017-02-09 10:31:20,794 ERROR akka.remote.EndpointWriter                
- dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient
[Actor[akka.tcp://flink@10.0.42.7:6123/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://flink@10.0.42.7:6123]
inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://flink@0.0.0.0:6123]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

**UPDATE**

I think I isolated the problem. Issue opened on github: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30874

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the issue opened on Github, you can understand that the real problem was in swarm native networking VIP assignment. I turned it off and everything works now.

Actually, there is no way up to now to turn it off from compose file, so, I had to switch to a scripted deploy rather than an automatic `docker stack deploy`.